# return all elements of a list in dart without knowing actual number of elements

Tags: arrays, list, dart

i have a dart function and i want to return some value after using all elements of a list.

```
Future<String> func() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("www.abc.com"));
  var document = parse(response.body);
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("*[class^='abc']");
```

Suppose `list` contains three elements, I want to return `textcontent` from all elements.

Like `list[0].textcontent`, `list[1].textcontent`, `list[2].textcontent`. Problem is that i will not know how many items this list will have. I could have used a `for` loop but i need smaller solution. I tried to use `forEach` but I couldn't make it work. because it returns `void` but my function needs to return `String`.

Comment: You are saying your method should return `String` but you have multiple `textcontent` you want to return. What about returning `Future<List<String>>` and the list contains each `textcontent` content?

Comment: `return [for (var element in list) element.textcontent];`

Comment: @julemand101 thank you for ur comment i think i can try this, i will let you know once i try this.

Comment: @jamesdlin i will let u know once i try this, thanks